# Changing separate images one at a time with onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to use JavaScript to produce a page with multiple image files that I want to change individually and separately when I click on them. The best way I can to describe it is if you can imagine a set of playing cards face down, and I want to be able to click each one and have it change to a different image, and to be able to click again to change back.

Please see JavaScript and code below that I have done so far. The script works on my first image, but not on any further images.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="imgOne" onclick="changeImageOne()" src="click_here.png" height="100" width="100">
<img id="imgTwo" onlick="changeImageTwo()" src="click_here.png" height="100" width="100">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var changeImageOne = function() {
  var imageOne = document.getElementById('imgOne');
  if (imageOne.src.match("i.jpg")) {
    imageOne.src = "click_here.png";
  } else {
    imageOne.src = "i.jpg";
  }
}
var changeImageTwo = function() {
  var imageTwo = document.getElementById('imgTwo');
  if (imageTwo.src.match("l.jpg")) {
    imageTwo.src = "click_here.png";
  } else {
    imageTwo.src = "l.jpg";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> typo @ `onlick`, it is `onclick`

```js
var changeImageOne = function() {
  var imageOne = document.getElementById('imgOne');
  if (imageOne.src.match("i.jpg")) {
    imageOne.src = "click_here.png";
  } else {
    imageOne.src = "i.jpg";
  }
  alert(imageOne.src);
}
var changeImageTwo = function() {
  var imageTwo = document.getElementById('imgTwo');
  if (imageTwo.src.match("l.jpg")) {
    imageTwo.src = "click_here.png";
  } else {
    imageTwo.src = "l.jpg";
  }
  alert(imageTwo.src);
}
```

```html
<img id="imgOne" onclick="changeImageOne()" src="click_here.png" height="100" width="100">
<img id="imgTwo" onclick="changeImageTwo()" src="click_here.png" height="100" width="100">
```

Comment: Arrghh. Thank you so much! Wish I had asked before I wasted two hours fiddling with the js!

Comment: @PJGannon I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript :

```
<script>
function SWAPImage(idv,oldimg,newimg){
    document.getElementById(idv).attributes.src.value=newimg;
    document.getElementById(idv).attributes["alt-src"].value = oldimg;
}
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<img class="image" src="a.jpg" alt-src="a_other.jpg" id="img1" onClick="SWAPImage(this.id,this.attributes.src.value,this.attributes['alt-src'].value)" />
<img class="image" src="b.jpg" alt-src="b_other.jpg" id="img2" onClick="SWAPImage(this.id,this.attributes.src.value,this.attributes['alt-src'].value)" />
<img class="image" src="c.jpg" alt-src="c_other.jpg" id="img3" onClick="SWAPImage(this.id,this.attributes.src.value,this.attributes['alt-src'].value)" />
```

I used alt-src attribute to store other image on it.When click on any image.It swap src with alt-src.